# Sharepoint task - add webpart to the form and recommended list items?

Tags: 2013

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I have a custom List called "Orders'. I also have a Task List setup. I would like to display "Recommended Orders" in the Task form. So when a User opens up a created Task, a web part also displays some recommended items from the Orders List.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is that, you want to show orders from Orders list to Task list/list forms,

If i am right ,then you can create relationships between Orders List & Task List by using  `lookup columns`. see below screenshot,

[image]

1. Go to Task List's setting.
2. Click on Create column.
3. Give name like`Recommended Orders`.
4. Select Lookup as Type.
5. Select List from which orders will come. In you case it's `Orders`
6. Select column that contains orders values.
7. Save.

Now all orders from Orders list will show up on task list.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Not entirely...

Let's put it a different way. I'll demonstrate with Support Tickets.

Lets say I am working with Two Lists:

1. Tasks
2. Support Knowledge Base

If my task name is titled: "SharePoint login issues", I would like a webpart displaying data, adjacent to the Task displaying a list of related "Knowledge base articles" that relate to "SharePoint login issues".

I'm trying to build a feature similar to the "See Also" panel, but the "See Also" panel isn't that good.

Comment: Ohk..You have added only one tag (2013) which is insufficient  to clearly understand your requirements. So please add related tags to your question. like visual-webpart OR sandboxed , csom/ssom/jsom/C# or something related to your requirement.